# Appium почему падает?

Tags: appium

```
**org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Error getting device platform version. Original error: Error while getting connected devices. Original error: Command '/usr/bin/adb -P 5037 -s 192.168.57.102\:5555 devices' exited with code 1 (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
```

**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: текстовую информацию лучше проводить в виде текста.